# Run Matlab script from terminal and display plot

Tags: macos, matlab, terminal

I running a Matlab 2016a script from terminal on my mac with

```
/Applications/MATLAB_R2016a.app/bin/matlab -nojvm -nodesktop -nosplash
```

The problem is that plots are not displayed. The error message is:

```
Error using plot
This functionality is no longer supported under the -nojvm startup option. For
more information, see "Changes to -nojvm Startup Option" in the MATLAB Release
Notes. To view the release note in your system browser, run
web('http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/release-notes.html#btsurqv-6',
'-browser').
```

Please help me to display plots in this operation mode.

Comment: I have the same exact error. Did you find a solution?